# Deployment process for custom modules in SugarCRM

Tags: php, git, deployment, version-control, sugarcrm

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to deploy custom modules from a development environment to staging or production. Reading from SugarCRM support pages (http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Knowledge_Base/02Administration/100Studio_and_Module_Builder/01_Best_Practices_When_Building_Custom_Modules/), all new modules should be built with Module Builder. The output of this is a `.zip` file which is a deployable unit. Then the support page says never to redeploy a package and all further modifications should be done with Studio.

> Once the module is deployed, you should use Studio to perform any additional configurations to your module ...

As I understand, Studio modifies files in the `custom/` directory and there's no deployable package with the changes (e.g. a `.zip` file). How can I deploy changes made with Studio to staging or production environments? I was thinking of using Git and have the modifications in `custom/` directory tracked. Then I could pull the changes to the desired environment. Is this a viable solution? Or has anyone come up with something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is a good way to manage your customizations in Sugar. Here are some additional resources that will help you find the best process:

- http://shortwhitebaldguy.com/blog/2012/08/managing-sugarcrm-customizations-in-git
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/SugarCRM.gitignore
- http://www.profilingsolutions.com/archive/sugarcrm-sdlc-monitoring-database-changes/
- http://prezi.com/iiempvwnnav9/sugarcon-managing-sugar-extensions-in-a-multi-developer-environment/

Comment: Thanks for the resources!